# How to add numbers with LC-3 program and have them display correctly in the registers?

Tags: assembly, lc3

Using LC-3 Assembly, I'm trying to set the values of R0 through R5 to 0. Then, I'm trying to assign 1 to R1, 2 to R2, and so on through setting 5 to R5. Finally, I'm trying to compute the sum and store the result in R0.

My code so far is below:

```
.ORIG x3000
AND R0,R0,#0
AND R1,R1,#0
AND R2,R2,#0
AND R3,R3,#0
AND R4,R4,#0
AND R5,R5,#0
ADD R1,R1,#1
ADD R2,R2,#2
ADD R3,R3,#3
ADD R4,R4,#4
ADD R5,R5,#5
ADD R0,R0,R1
ADD R0,R0,R2
ADD R0,R0,R3
ADD R0,R0,R4
ADD R0,R0,R5
TRAP    x25
.END
```

The problem is that when I run the program, the registers end up having the following values:
R0 is 32767, R1 is -1, R2 is 2, R3 is 3, R4 is 4, and R5 is 5. Registers 2 through 5 are correct but R0 and R1 are wrong, and I have no idea how to fix the problem.

Comment: This code is correct, it may be a problem with the simulator you are using.

Comment: Is there any way to properly configure the simulator to have it run properly?

Comment: The answer to that is highly dependent on what lc3 simulator you are using.  

Before I move on.  Are you sure you are in the correct directory and that the simulator is indeed running that code?

And if so what lc3 simulator are you using?

Comment: This is the website that I got the LC-3 simulator from. http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072467509/student_view0/lc-3_simulator.html

Comment: If you single-step, are R0 and R1 correct before the `trap`?

Comment: What do you mean single-step? I tried running the program without the `trap x25` and R0 and R1 are still incorrect

Comment: Your LC-3 simulator has a debugger built in, right?  See http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=606223&seqNum=3 for a description of what single-stepping means in a debugger for C.  The asm equivalent should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the comments and that you are using the official LC-3 simulator from the book.

That simulator will step into trap service routines.  What you are seeing is R0/R1 being clobbered by the code to handle the trap x25 instruction.

Your code is correct.  Just put a breakpoint at the TRAP x25 instruction and examine the registers at that point.